# Twitter Audience insight for other twitter handles

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Is it possible to extract audience insight information of other Twitter handles? For example: can i get audience insight of @BarackObama provided i have Ads API access or is it restricted to your own Ads API handle ?

Comment: may i know why this was downvoted ? it could help me ask questions better in the future

Comment: I suspect this would be because this is not exactly an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question - it relates to a single service and asks a very broad question with no particular programming angle.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter's Engagement API and Advertiser API both require a user context. You can only get access to engagement information relating to the user token you have access to. If you don't have access to the President's token i.e. they have not logged in to your app, you will be unable to access those kind of insights.